# Как установить библиотечку в C# Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Нашёл на гитхабе библиотечку https://github.com/xamarin/mqtt .

Создал новое приложение Cross-Platform/Мобильное приложение (Xamarin.Forms).

В консоли выполнил:

```
Install-Package System.Net.Mqtt -Pre
```

Вроде как выполняется всё норм. Как увидеть, что библиотечка установилась?

Вставляю код:

```
var configuration = new MqttConfiguration();
```

Но почему-то не работает. Подскажите, плиз, как настроить либу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. В C# и Xamarin не силен)

Comment: вроде ставится, как подключить к своему приложению?

Comment: 1. Я создал новое приложение Cross-Platform/Мобильное приложение (Xamarin.Forms).
2. В консоли выполнил: Install-Package System.Net.Mqtt -Pre . Вроде как выполняется всё норм. Как увидеть, что библиотечка установилась? 
3. Вставляю код: var configuration = new MqttConfiguration(); - не работает

Comment: Уточнил в вопросе. Сможете помочь?

Comment: Ссылку на библиотеку в проекте проверьте.

Comment: Подскажите, плиз. У меня с С# очень плохо в этом смысле

Comment: Добавил скриншот ошибки.

Comment: Попробуйте написать полный путь: `System.Net.Mqtt.MqttConfiguration();` и там же указано что: `using System.Net.Mqtt; using System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk;` подключать именно так

Comment: http://prntscr.com/n9yps4

Comment: Список зависимостей покажите полностью.

Comment: Так норм? http://prntscr.com/na272o

Answer (score 0):

Установленные библиотеки можно посмотреть, перейдя в пункт меню `Средства -> Диспетчер пакетов NuGet -> Управление пакетами NuGet для решения` во вкладке `Установлено`. Также проверьте наличие пакета в обозревателе решений в разделе ссылок